# Allowing 1 Directory on a Webserver to be accessed for Includes by others

Tags: php, .htaccess, include

The circumstances are this, I have a hosting package for my website, that doesn't allow me access to the php.ini or httpd.conf. I have taken on various clients, that want to keep the current hosting packages.

What I want to do is allow access to a directory on a particular path, with in my domain, which I can keep php includes in. That I can then share across various clients sites, so I don't have to access all the sites and update all the files.

A friend of mine mentioned that curl and fopen could do it but would add a lag. Is it possible to use, and I know very little about them, .htaccess document to open that directory for read only access for include requests from other web servers. Obviously I want to keep my webspace as secure as possible. Advice and help please.

Comment: curl or fopen and then eval() on the code is not a really good idea. if your includes are php files/functions/classes why not create your own API and build client websites around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that accessing your includes via curl/fopen using URLs will mean that you're accessing those PHP includes as if they were regular PHP scripts. Unless you configure your server to serve up .php files as plain text in that particular directly, the include scripts will be EXECUTED, and all you get are their output.

e.g.

`include.php` on your centralized "include" server

```
<?php

function foo() {
    echo 'hello from foo';
}
```

some script on a client site:

```
<?php
include('http://includes.example.com/inculde.php');
```

will essentially include NOTHING. The `include.php` script is producing no output. You will not get `foo()` function available in your client site, because no PHP code was returned by the remote site.

On the other hand, if you had something like this:

```
<?php
echo '<' . '?php';
?>               

function foo() {
  echo 'foo';
}
```

then you WOULD get plaintext that happens to be PHP code, and the include would work as expected.

However, you should NOT be using `include()` with remote files. It opens up a whole can of attack vectors for a malicious user. Perhaps you have a DNS glitch, and the attack can remap the IP of `include.example.com`, so that your client sites are now loading code from a server under their control, and now all of your clients are compromised.

Perhaps there's a network glitch and for whatever reason your central include server is not reachable from the client machine's - now their site is dead in the water because your server isn't available.

Basically, you're introducing a single point of failure into your system, where the failure will take out ALL of your clients at the same time. Not a good system, at all.